# java txt file is over writing when use file and formatter

Tags: java, file, methods, io, formatter

So i have tried every thing but the files keeps over writing the first line, i am passing these methods to another class so the three arguments in method add_records are passed through a scanner.

here is the creating/opening method :

```
    public class Io_Files{


    private Formatter output;

public void open_file_normal(String filename) throws IOException
{
    {
        try
        {
            FileWriter fileWriter = new FileWriter(filename, true);
            output = new Formatter(filename);
        }
        catch(FileNotFoundException fileNotFoundException)
        {
            System.err.println("Error");
        }
    }
}
```

and here is the code for adding record method:

```
    public void add_records(String a, String b, int c) throws       FileNotFoundException{


output.format ("[%s, %s, %d]%n", a, b, c);



}
```

please if you are able to help provide some comments on why and where to put the code so i can learn too.

cheers

Comment: so if i am not writing this code then why its overwriting. also how can i write it? @mkieric

Comment: You've set the `append` flag, but you are not using that `FileWriter`. You have two options: instantiate a `new Formatter()` with your `fileWriter`, or use `formatter.format()` output and append it with `fileWriter.append()`.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try using

```
output = new Formatter(fileWriter);
```

instead of

```
output = new Formatter(filename);
```

Comment: Hey, thanx this works. OFC i wouldnt notice it haha. i tried to upvote it but i need 15 reps. sorry